# How to fix error Failed assertion: line 1869 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedWidth': is not true. when i'm using GridView.count in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm using GridView.count in the showModalBottomSheet when click button.
But i got this error 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1869 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedWidth': is not true.
package:flutter/…/rendering/viewport.dart:1869
Can anyone help? Please.

Here it's my code

```
loatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {
      showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return SizedBox.expand(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: const Text("Add"),
                ),
                GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Text("item 1"),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("item 2"),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['constraints.hasBoundedWidth': is not true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020068/constraints-hasboundedwidth-is-not-true)

Comment: Wrap Gridview with Expanded, it will provide needed width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try it set width, height of SizedBox

Use

 SizedBox(width: xx, height: xx)

Instead of

 SizedBox.expand